# AngularJS testing directives can't compile template from URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm writing tests for a directive. I want pass in a templateURL and then test various functionality of it using the built in JQlite library.

For some reason my template doesn't seem to compile, though Jasmine doesn't give me any errors.

my relevant app structure is:

```
/app
../partials/
../tests/
```

I have my karma.conf setup so:

```
files: [
  ...
  'tests/*.js',
  'partials/*.html'      
],

preprocessors: {
  'partials/*.html':'ng-html2js'
},

plugins: [
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
  'karma
]
```

My test code looks like this:

```
describe('mapInputs.customForm', function () {
  var elm, scope;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('partials/test/tmpl.html'));

  beforeEach(inject( function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;

    elm = angular.element('<div><ng-map-inputs map-inputs=""></ng-map-inputs></div>');
    console.log('elm', elm);
    elm = $compile(elm)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    console.log('elm', elm);
  }));

  it('should reveal custom form', function () {
    // elm.find('div') returns an empty object
  });
});
```

And the output:

```
LOG: 'elm', Object{length: 1, 0: <div><ng-map-inputs map-inputs=""></ng-map-inputs></div>}

LOG: 'elm', Object{length: 1, 0: <div class="ng-scope"><ng-map-inputs map-inputs=""></ng-map-inputs></div>}
```

As I said, I don't get any errors, but the output of the console logs is not what I expect. It seems like the template is not being compiled? But surely Jasmine would complain if no template was found?

Comment: Too complicated to debug by sight... please create a Codepen

Comment: Just wanted to see if there was anything obvious I was missing.

Comment: Nothing is missing but a man (or woman's) brain can't compile that into bit code and see what's wrong, a browser has to do that, so make a fiddle.

Comment: OK. I have got part way with a plunkr. I'm unsure how to access the templates and pre-process them with this method though. http://plnkr.co/edit/zAIBZachWFCd6GEzp7Hh?p=preview

Comment: Your directive is named `mapInputs`, but in your test you are using `ng-map-inputs`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Angualr resolves these names for you. `mapInputs` == `ng-map-inputs`

Comment: Sorry, yes it needs to be `map-inputs` to work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I wasn't loading the actual directive in the `karma.conf.js`:

```
 files: [
  ...
  'path/to/directive/map-inputs.directive.js',  // <-- wasn't being loaded before
  'tests/*.js',
  'partials/*.html'      
 ],
```